# facebook share button showing wrong thumbnails

Tags: facebook, image, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph, share-button

I'm using the Facebook Share Button widget, which in general is working fine.

It's showing the image declared in the "og:image" meta tag , but additionally it's showing other images that are in the page, but that are not relevant to the actual content of the page. I don't want these additional thumbnails to show, I just need to show the image declared in the "og:image" meta tag, I don't want any other pictures.

This is the link I'm talking about.

http://www.semana.com/tecnologia/novedades/multimedia/4g-proyecciones-colombia/392262-3

The article is in Spanish, so to clear it out "Compartir" means Share in English, so the Facebook Share Button is the one that says "Compartir".

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try running it through the Facebook URL Debugger

Comment: This is what Facebook thinks about your page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.semana.com%2Ftecnologia%2Fnovedades%2Fmultimedia%2F4g-proyecciones-colombia%2F392262-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found out what was happening...

Many thanks to Ranveer and WizKid. I didn't know about that debugger. It was because the image had lower resolution.

Link for the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/